# R Markdown - How can I give rows different formats?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm currently working with a dataframe that has many numeric values, some are percentages, some are dollar values, some are just scalar values. I can format (using `formattable` package) columns with the appropriate formats, but I would love being able to do the same for **rows** instead.

Do you know how to achieve this? In particular, this is for LaTeX/PDF output

Reproducible example:

```r
structure(list(seg1 = c(117.67, 117.68, -69.14, 0.0100000000000051, 
-186.81, 0, 0.4, 0, 79, 168.18, 387.95, 67.272), seg2 = c(174.29, 
212.75, 212.76, 38.46, 38.47, 0, 0, 0.35, 79, 168.18, 387.95, 
135.7825), seg3 = c(458.08, 516.15, 352.38, 58.07, -105.7, 0, 
0.25, 0, 79, 168.18, 387.95, 42.045)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Reference utility to customer", 
"HP_PPM30 utility to customer", "HP_wireless utility to customer", 
"Pricing room product 1", "Pricing room product 2", "Reference bought", 
"Product 1 bought", "Product 2 bought", "Reference mg contr.", 
"Product 1 mg contr.", "Product 2 mg contr.", "Profits per segment"
))
```

Yields

```
                                    seg1     seg2     seg3
Reference utility to customer    117.670 174.2900  458.080
HP_PPM30 utility to customer     117.680 212.7500  516.150
HP_wireless utility to customer  -69.140 212.7600  352.380
Pricing room product 1             0.010  38.4600   58.070
Pricing room product 2          -186.810  38.4700 -105.700
Reference bought                   0.000   0.0000    0.000
Product 1 bought                   0.400   0.0000    0.250
Product 2 bought                   0.000   0.3500    0.000
Reference mg contr.               79.000  79.0000   79.000
Product 1 mg contr.              168.180 168.1800  168.180
Product 2 mg contr.              387.950 387.9500  387.950
Profits per segment               67.272 135.7825   42.045
```

Is it possible to get the **ROWS** that say "mg contr." to show currency format, and the rows that say "bought" a percentage format? I can do columns using `%>% currency()`, but no idea about rows. This would have to be implemented at R-markdown/latex level of course.

For further clarity, this is doable in LaTeX or just using plain inline R and markdown tables, but it'd be awesome having a programmatic way of achieving this.

Comment: https://gt.rstudio.com/ is a thought

Comment: SebastianRivas, I think it would be beneficial if you provided some reproducible data, either with `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`, and your intended output. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can use `dplyr`'s `case_when` to create a new column of *string* values, each formatted according to some rule. You can use `scales` for the formatting. For example

```
output %>%
  mutate(new_value = case_when(
    variable %in% c("income", "taxable income") ~ scales::dollar(old_value),
    variable %in% c("loss (pct)", "tax rate") ~ scales::percent(old_value)
  )
```

Comment: Wouldn't that format each COLUMN differently, instead of each row?

Comment: No, it wouldn't